# Using JTA with Spring +hibernate JPA+Glassfish 3.1 Transaction not committing

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, glassfish, jta

I have been struggling with this issues and i have searched the entire internet but to no avail. I am hoping you guy can help me
I using glassfish 3.1 with hibernate JPA and spring 3.
I have configured a datasource and pool in Glassfish to target MYSQL
please find my configurations

the Web.xml , i configured the persistence units.

```
  <persistence-unit-ref>
    <description>Persistence Unit for PlyPlus</description>
    <persistence-unit-ref-name>
    persistence/zeneJPA
    </persistence-unit-ref-name>
    <persistence-unit-name>
    ZeneJPA
    </persistence-unit-name>
    </persistence-unit-ref>
```

The application-context

```
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.binarydna.store" />
    <bean        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor">
     <property name="persistenceUnits">
     <map>
     <entry key="ZeneJPA" value="persistence/zeneJPA">
     </entry>
     </map>
     </property>
     </bean>
        <!-- 
     <bean id="entityManagerFactory"   class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
     <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="ZeneJPA"/>
     </bean>
     -->
     <!-- We want to use Spring's declarative @Transaction management -->
     <tx:annotation-driven />
     <jee:jndi-lookup id="entityManagerFactory"    jndi-name="persistence/zeneJPA" /> 
     <tx:jta-transaction-manager />
```

Persistence.xml

```
  <persistence-unit name="ZeneJPA" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/zeneDS</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
    <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class"    value="org.hibernate.transaction.SunONETransactionManagerLookup"/>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
    <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true"/>
    <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class,hbm"/>
    <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory"/>
```

the method/class that saves the object

```
@Repository("AdminDAO")
@Transactional
public class AdminDAOImpl implements AdminDAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;


    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }

@Override
    public boolean saveCustomer(Customer customer) {
         boolean saved = false;
            try {
                if (customer.getId() == null) {
                    this.em.persist(customer);
                }
                else {
                    this.em.merge(customer);
                }
                saved = true;
            }
            catch (Exception p) {
                saved = false;
                return saved;
            }
            return saved;
    }
}
```

Please help me out here what am i doing wrong??
This configuration generates the tables but just does not commit the transaction.
When i step through using the degugger it actually calls the save but does not commit the transaction.
Please what is the appropraite configuration to get spring transaction working with Glassfish? Thanks I appreciate all the help.

Comment: Have you tried marking up saveCustomer with the appropriate @Transactional annotation value(s)?

Comment: i will try but i marked the entire class.is there a difference

Comment: i just add the @Transactional annotional to the method and still it did not commit.can I see an appropriate configuration that works with Glassfish?

Comment: Hi! How did you solved this issue? I think I'm facing the same problem! Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using a Java EE 6 full container to support a Spring App? Tomcat wouldn't be the enough? I'm pretty sure that if you expose you class as a session bean, the container will take care about JTA transactions for you, but with Spring... I'm really not too sure.